# How do i return an Array from a nested Array JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, arraylist

Im trying to get a list of individual tags from the below but i keep getting undefined. What am i doing wrong?

```js
initialState = [{name: "John",tags: ["primary", "secondary"]}, {name: "Mark",tags: ["primary"]}];

let tags = initialState.forEach((el) => {
  if (el.tags) {
    el.tags.map((tag) => {
      return tag;
    }, []);
  }
})
console.log(tags);
```

Expected Result

`tags = ["primary","secondary","primary"]`

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't return anything. Your inner `map` is also an useless expression statement, because the return is immediately discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return an array. To get all the tags in one list, you can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) as follows:

```js
const initialState = [
  { name: "John", tags: ["primary", "secondary"] },
  { name: "Mark", tags:["primary"] }
];

const tags = initialState.flatMap(({ tags = [] }) => tags);   

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively to the other answer using `map()` and then `flat()`

```js
initialState = [{name: "John",tags: ["primary", "secondary"]}, {name: "Mark",tags: ["primary"]}];

let tags = initialState.map(el=>[...el.tags]).flat();
console.log(tags);
```